# multi-thread causes memory leak

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy

I'm made an application that receives data from an API every 10 seconds and this is all done within 2 threads. I can't figure out why there is a memory leak as I free all that I used after the task is done.

I want to apologize if I'm missing or doing something wrong as I'm new to threading and I don't fully understand how it works.

I tried to remake this: [Synchronizing Threads and GUI in a Delphi Application](https://www.thoughtco.com/synchronizing-threads-and-gui-delphi-application-1058159) but failed as I don't understand what is going on. If someone can please explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it or make it better.

Current Code:

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP,
  IdSSLOpenSSL, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    grpLuno: TGroupBox;
    lblBid: TLabel;
    lblRolling24HourVolume: TLabel;
    grpBinance: TGroupBox;
    tmrRefresh: TTimer;
    lblPrice: TLabel;
    lblBinanceVolume: TLabel;
    lbl1: TLabel;
    lbl24hChange: TLabel;
    procedure Refresh;
    procedure tmrRefreshTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type
  TGetLuno = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

type
  TGetBinance = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  djson, DateUtils, Math;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NoMove or SWP_NoSize);
  Refresh;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.Refresh;
begin
  with TGetLuno.Create do
  begin
    FreeOnTerminate := True;
  end;

  with TGetBinance.Create do
  begin
    FreeOnTerminate := True;
  end;

end;

procedure TfrmMain.tmrRefreshTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Refresh;
end;

{ TGetLuno }

procedure TGetLuno.Execute;
var
  httpclient: TIdHTTP;
  sdata: string;
  jdata: TJSON;
begin
  httpclient := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    sdata := httpclient.Get('https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/ticker?pair=XBTZAR');
  finally
    httpclient.Free;
  end;

  jdata := TJSON.Parse(sdata);
  try
    frmMain.lblBid.Caption := 'Price: R ' + jdata['bid'].AsString;
    frmMain.lblRolling24HourVolume.Caption := 'Volume: ' + jdata['rolling_24_hour_volume'].AsString;
  finally
    jdata.Free;
  end;
end;

{ TGetBinance }

procedure TGetBinance.Execute;
var
  httpclient: TIdHTTP;
  sdata: string;
  jdata: TJSON;
  SocketOpenSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  httpclient := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  SocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  SocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
  httpclient.IOHandler := SocketOpenSSL;
  try
    sdata := httpclient.Get('https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCUSDT');
  finally
    httpclient.Free;
  end;

  jdata := TJSON.Parse(sdata);
  try
    frmMain.lblPrice.Caption := 'Price: $ ' + jdata['lastPrice'].AsString;
    frmMain.lblBinanceVolume.Caption := 'Volume: ' + jdata['volume'].AsString;

    if StrToFloat(StringReplace(jdata['priceChangePercent'].AsString, '.', ',', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase])) > 0 then
      frmMain.lbl24hChange.Font.Color := clLime
    else
      frmMain.lbl24hChange.Font.Color := clRed;
    frmMain.lbl24hChange.Caption := StringReplace(FloatToStr(RoundTo(StrToFloat(StringReplace(jdata['priceChangePercent'].AsString, '.', ',', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase])), -2)), ',', '.', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]) + ' %';
  finally
    jdata.Free;
  end;
end;

initialization
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;

end.
```

Comment: The first obvious problem is that you are accessing GUI objects from your threads. You can't do that. This has been discussed hundreds of times here, so I won't try to repeat the advice, just encourage you to research that topic.

Comment: http://activcust.com/CanIUseVclFromThread.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your thread execute methods, you are accessing VCL `frmMain` components directly.

Since the VCL framework must be executed in the main thread only, you will need to divert those calls. Use [TThread.Synchronize()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) or [TThread.Queue()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue) for example:

```
jdata := TJSON.Parse(sdata);
try
  Synchronize(
    procedure
    begin
      frmMain.lblPrice.Caption := 'Price: $ ' + jdata['lastPrice'].AsString;
      frmMain.lblBinanceVolume.Caption := 'Volume: ' + jdata['volume'].AsString;

      if StrToFloat(StringReplace(jdata['priceChangePercent'].AsString, '.',
        ',', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase])) > 0 then
        frmMain.lbl24hChange.Font.Color := clLime
      else
        frmMain.lbl24hChange.Font.Color := clRed;
      frmMain.lbl24hChange.Caption :=
        StringReplace(FloatToStr(RoundTo(StrToFloat(StringReplace(jdata
        ['priceChangePercent'].AsString, '.', ',', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase])
        ), -2)), ',', '.', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]) + ' %';
    end);
finally
  jdata.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I also noticed the memory comes from me not freeing ```SocketOpenSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;``` I have fixed this now and thanks to your example I now understand how to use Syncronize